# Joomla 2.5 Jquery Cannot call method of null

Tags: jquery, joomla, null, element, slideup

Hi guys I am using Joomla 2.5 with Jquery and I got this strange error in my chrome console:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'slideUp' of null "
```

here is index.php header section:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/jscript.js"></script>
    <jdoc:include type="head" />
```

and jscript.js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var slider = document.getElementById("login-form");

    alert (slider);

    $("#login-form").slideUp(100); <- error is on this line

});
```

I tested it and alert showed : [object HTMLFormElement], so it meas "login-form" realy exists. can't figure out why am I getting

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'slideUp' of null "
```

Please, can you help me!!!!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most probably your jquery code is conflicting with mootools.
Try this using

> `jQuery.noConflict();`

Your code will be like below-

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function(){

    var slider = document.getElementById("login-form");

    alert (slider);

    $j("#login-form").slideUp(100);

});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was about to kill myself... before I read your post