# Hide div when another div is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla

I know theres lots of answers on this problem, but I've read through all I can find but still cant get it to work.

I have a div which i need to be hidden if another div is empty, or just containing whitespace.

```
<div id="rt-main" class="mb12">
    <div class="rt-grid-12">
        <div class="rt-block component-block main-overlay-light">
            <div id="rt-mainbody">
                <div class="component-content">
                    <div class="blog-featured"></div>
```

( I want to hide div.mb12 when div blog-featured = '    '  )

My closest bet is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   str = $('div.section').text();
   if($.trim(str) === "") {
     $('div.section').hide();
   }
});
```

But I get all sorts of errors in the console when trying.

Now I've got "TypeError: Cannot call method 'text' of null"

Comment: I don't see a div with class `.section` Seems like you are not selecting anything...

Comment: If you had a `div` with an id = "section", the jQuery to get it would be `$("#section")`. Mind the `#`. `$(".section")` will get elements with the "section" class, but you don't have any of these in your code either.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13438464/joomla-2-5-jquery-cannot-call-method-of-null

Comment: Sounds like $ is not jQuery

Comment: `$('div.blog-featured')` would never result in `null` with jQuery.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I posted the wrong code. It's edited now.

Comment: Nothing wrong here. Where you getting the errors? (browser?) http://jsfiddle.net/RaphaelDDL/TMPQF/

Comment: I get it in the chrome debugger

TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'ready'

Comment: Same again. `$(document)` would return a jQuery object, not the DOM element. Are you using Prototype.js by any chance?

Comment: @HåkanBylund That message about `ready` is very different than what you posted in your question.  This implies that you are trying to do `document.ready` without the `$()`.  Please be sure the code you have posted is actually the one you are using.

Comment: @FelixKling No, not that I am aware of.

Comment: @JamesMontagne It is the same.

Copied from Chrome debugger:

Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'ready' index.php:60
FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init(). all.js:55
$(document).ready(function() {
   str = $('div.section').text();
   if($.trim(str) === "") {
     $('div.section').hide();
   }
});
TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'ready'

Comment: @FelixKling See comments on gibberish's answer.  Not prototype, but mootools and some other stuff.

Comment: @HåkanBylund Your question states:  ""TypeError: Cannot call method 'text' of null"... implying you made it past the `ready` call which clearly now is not the case.

Comment: @JamesMontagne I understand that, but how could that be?   Write it off as a mootools(?) conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the actual site (not included in the question), you have this:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

This makes it so that `$` is no longer jquery.  Most likely because one of the many other libraries you have included uses the `$` name.  You can simply change your code to use `jQuery` in place of `$`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { ...
```

Alternatively, you can assign jQuery to a different variable name:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function(){ ...
```

Comment: Oh, that did it! I was just about to jump out the window. Sorry for the bad explaining and such, I'll do better in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You want this -

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var str = jQuery('div.blog-featured').text();
    if (jQuery.trim(str) === "") {
        jQuery('div.mb12').hide();
    }
});
```

Demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/PqXWJ/20/

Comment: I get this:
TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'ready'

Comment: As I said above `$` is not `jQuery`! You got a problem since `$` is something else.

Comment: Obviously I'm a noob, and I suck. 
I've been at this for two days and I'm getting desperate.

If it isn't jQuery i suppose it's JS?  I still just declare it in <script type="javascript/text> I suppose?

Comment: Still getting: TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'ready'
Maybe I'm doing some declarations wrong?

Comment: Are you loading the jQuery library first? See my example.

Comment: @gibberish Yes I am. I think.

Maybe I should not post links to the site, but it is www.elvina-marin.se    If you wanna verify that the library is properly declared

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading the jQuery library before your script?  Do you have something like this in the `<head>` tags of your page?

```
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        etc etc
    </script>
```

Comment: I have this

    <script src="/media/system/js/mootools-core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/media/system/js/core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/media/system/js/caption.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/media/system/js/mootools-more.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/plugins/system/jqueryeasy/jquerynoconflict.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: uhm... not sure how to add as code in comments.

 <script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"; type="text/javascript">

Comment: You have mootools, some sort of noconflict plugin.  This is all very relevant to the question.  You likely have a conflict between all of these libraries and plugins.

Comment: @JamesMontagne I see. I've tried the no.confilct option and also tried to install plugins to joomla to handle jquery libraries.

Can this be done with regular JS, to avoid conflicts?

Comment: this is a bad method for importing jquery. please refer to my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12471067/importing-jquery-into-joomla/12473933

Comment: @Lodder I've added the code according to your guide. It gives me this in the header:

  <script src="http://www.elvina-marin.se/templates/rt-metropolis/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

but the problem persists

Comment: @HåkanBylund see my answer.  The question did not include enough information to give an answer.  Seeing the real site I was able to find the issue.