# JQuery does not trigger any event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have two ASP pages. One `head.master` which has some contents as well as contents which are retrieved from the `Default.aspx` page. Because I can get script URL from the `head.master` page, I have it setup there along with the HTML/JQuery contents like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
... //other contents here
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolderSearch" runat="server">
       <!-- Search stuff goes here -->
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
... //other contents here
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

In my `Default.aspx` page I have the contents like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="head.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_default" title="WESTMED Medical Group  - Top Doctors in New York" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Ektron.Cms.Controls" Namespace="Ektron.Cms.Controls" TagPrefix="CMS" %>
 <%@ OutputCache Duration="900" VaryByParam="none" %>
<asp:Content ID="topContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="topContent" Runat="Server">
... //other stuff goes here
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="ContentPlaceHolderSearch" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderSearch" Runat="Server">
            <input style="background: url(images/find.png) no-repeat; padding-left: 20px;" type="text" id="TextBox1" />
            <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Search" class="locButton" />
            <script type = "text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#Button1").click(function () {
                        var textbox = document.getElementById("TextBox1").value;
                        if (textbox.length > 0) {
                            //alert("Search query is not empty and redirecting...");
                            window.location.href = "http://mymed.com/search_results.aspx?searchtext=" + textbox + "&folderid=0&searchfor=all&orderby=title&orderdirection=ascending";
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("Search query is empty");
                        }
                    });
                    $('#TextBox1').keyup(function () {
                        var $th = $(this);
                        $th.val($th.val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, ''));
                    });
                    $('#TextBox1').keypress(function (e) {
                        var textbox = document.getElementById("TextBox1").value;
                        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
                        if (code == 13) {
                            if (textbox.length > 0) {
                                e.preventDefault();
                                window.location.href = "http://mymed.com/search_results.aspx?searchtext=" + textbox + "&folderid=0&searchfor=all&orderby=title&orderdirection=ascending";
                            }
                            else {
                                e.preventDefault();
                                alert("Search query is empty");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
    </script> 
</asp:Content>
```

Looking at the output HTML source of the page I see the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="ctl00_Head1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="/" id="aspnetForm">
... //other contents goes here
<input style="background: url(images/find.png) no-repeat; padding-left: 20px;" type="text" id="TextBox1" />
            <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Search" class="locButton" />
            <script type = "text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#Button1").click(function () {
                        var textbox = document.getElementById("TextBox1").value;
                        if (textbox.length > 0) {
                            //alert("Search query is not empty and redirecting...");
                            window.location.href = "http://mymed.com/search_results.aspx?searchtext=" + textbox + "&folderid=0&searchfor=all&orderby=title&orderdirection=ascending";
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("Search query is empty");
                        }
                    });
                    $('#TextBox1').keyup(function () {
                        var $th = $(this);
                        $th.val($th.val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, ''));
                    });
                    $('#TextBox1').keypress(function (e) {
                        var textbox = document.getElementById("TextBox1").value;
                        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
                        if (code == 13) {
                            if (textbox.length > 0) {
                                e.preventDefault();
                                window.location.href = "http://mymed.com/search_results.aspx?searchtext=" + textbox + "&folderid=0&searchfor=all&orderby=title&orderdirection=ascending";
                            }
                            else {
                                e.preventDefault();
                                alert("Search query is empty");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
    </script>
... //other contents goes here
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I press the button nothing happens. I press the enter key nothing happens. I can enter special characters and it doesn't do the validation. I looked at other ASPX questions and I am thinking the script does not load before the contents. Please help me resolve this issue.

Console screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Do you have any javascript error in your console ?

Comment: Can you open in chrome, F12 and show here a screenshot of the Network pane?

Comment: If there are no javascript errors in the console, it's likely a timing issue. To test this, console out the element you're binding the event too immediately before the binding.

      console.dir($("#Button1"));
       $("#Button1").click(function () {....

if you get "e.fn.init[1]" if the element exists, or e.fn.init[0] if the dom element does not exist at the time of the binding.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I looked at the console under `Sources` and I see there is an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'click' of null` for the button. So maybe the script is not loading on time? How would I fix it?

Comment: @ejc That displays the `null` value :/!!! I wonder why it is null...

Comment: It sounds like that $ is not jQuery since $("#id") will never return null

Comment: What do I change the `$` to? I have always used the `$` but with ASP it is giving a lot of issues :/

Comment: Also you really should update that jQuery version. It is from February of 2009. It is very outdated.

Comment: Your output page works fine in a jsFiddle, so I tried your raw HTML in a HTML page and that also works in Chrome... What browser are you using?

Comment: I Updated my code to reflect the new JQuery link. Chrome 32.0.1700.76 (up to date) and IE 10 (up to date)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie It works fine in Plain HTML but it doesn't work through the ASP pages :/

Comment: As ASP just churns out raw HTML pages, that is a little nuts... Is there any more Javascript in the parts you commented out?

Comment: From which page? Default or head.master? I tried to do it both HEAD and in BODY. Same effect.

Comment: Have you saved your entire output as a html file and loaded that into Chrome? I could only try your snippet.

Comment: I do have it but we are using CMS but I doubt it would cause any issues.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46019/discussion-between-trueblueaussie-and-sikni8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer for everyone else's benefit:

As you have found, [in our chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46019/discussion-between-trueblueaussie-and-sikni8), your CMS is already using jQuery under another alias.

The link you found was:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13438464/joomla-2-5-jquery-cannot-call-method-of-nul‌​l](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13438464/joomla-2-5-jquery-cannot-call-method-of-nul%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bl)

But if another jQuery is already in your CMS you will want to use that version instead.

*Never assume anything when dealing with someone else's code.* Use something like [Fiddler2](http://fiddler2.com/) to view what your browser is pulling down.

Comment: Can you please make `Fiddler2` in a link for easier access :) Thanks! Great help!!!